# average 90th percentile response time and average response time

Tags: performance-testing

In my test,i observed that value of average 90th percentile and value of average response time is same,say 28.

Can someone assist in which cases it might happened??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be the case that response time for all samplers is equal or similar.

- **Average Response Time**  is basically [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean), to wit sum of response times for **all** samplers divided by their count.
- **90% percentile** is a [statistical measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile), in case of JMeter it means that 90% of the sampler response times were smaller than or equal to this time

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Request Statistics Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421515-Request-Statistics-Report)
- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)